# how to get value to a variable using wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

please any one tell me what I have to do to get what i write in textctrl to a variable.

```
from visual import *
import wx
L = 320

w = window(width=2*(L+window.dwidth), height=L+window.dheight+window.menuheight,
       menus=True, title='Widgets')
p=w.panel
d = 20
tc = wx.TextCtrl(p, pos=(1.4*L,90),size=(150,90))
yy=GetValue()
```

GetValue is not working here. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to get the content of the textctrl named as `tc`. In that case this line

`yy = GetValue()` in your code should be

`yy = tc.GetValue()`

I would also recommend you to use some meaningful names for the variables. For an instance instead of `yy` use something like `textctrlValue` or `textctrlContent` or `tcValue` or `tcContent`, so that you know what this variable is actually for.

Comment: Can you provide your complete code in your question

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean `yy = tc.GetValue()` (last line of your code) which actually gets the value from the [`wx.TextCtrl`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html) you've created.

Your code will raise a `NameError` as it is now.